# Sencha Touch Carousel with inactive slides visible either side

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, carousel

I'm looking to create a Sencha Touch carousel that doesn't only show the current active slide. I want to have the main active slide visible in the middle, but also have the slides either side visible too.

How is this possible?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

As you can see, the slides either side are visible and a little greyed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post explains how to do it, they use it in their app: http://www.sencha.com/blog/using-the-leap-motion-controller-with-sencha-touch/

They use this code:

```
itemLength: browserWidth * 0.8
```